# How to manage secrets in expo both for react native and web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, environment-variables

How can I manage sercrets in expo app for web and for mobile? on the expo website there is https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/securestore/ however it does not work for web, I wanted to go hybrid - separate package for web and for mobile and I have found a package

```
npm i react-native-config
```

so that would work for mobile, but when I do

```
npm i dotenv
```

to manage those for web it seems to be interfering with react-navigation as all imports get red underline.
Thanks